# puppeteer Error : Navigating frame was detached on page.goto

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer

```
 import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import express = require('express');
import bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';



import os = require('os');


const app = express();

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();


app.post('/', jsonParser, async (req, res) => {

  let browser;

  try {
    // Optional window and viewport dimensions config
    const width = 1920;
    const height = 1080;

    dotenv.config();

    const args = process.argv;
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: 'new',
      executablePath: process.env.CHROMIUM_PATH,
      args: [`--window-size=${width},${height}`,
        `--no-sandbox`,
        `--disable-setuid-sandbox`,
        `--incognito`,
        `--ignore-certificate-errors`,
        `--disable-dev-shm-usage`,
        `--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36`]
    });



    console.log('body - ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

    const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();

    await page.setViewport({
      width: 1024,
      height: 7500,
      deviceScaleFactor: 1,
      isMobile: false
    });

    console.log('Navigating to page');

    // This is where I get the error
    await page.goto(req.body.spurl, {
      waitUntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0'],
    });


    console.log('Currently on page - ' + await page.title());

 } catch (ex) {
    console.log(`Error: ${ex.message}`);
    console.log(ex);
    await browser.close();
    res.status(404).send(ex.message);
  }
  finally {
    await browser.close();
  }

});


app.listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
console.log(`Running`);
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /home/pptruser


ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=24576"

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci --only=production


# Bundle app source
COPY . .

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
  libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
  libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
  libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \
  ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils authbind sudo \
  && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable libxss1 \
  --no-install-recommends \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
ENV CHROMIUM_PATH google-chrome-stable


RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
  && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
  && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
  && chown -R pptruser:pptruser ./node_modules \
  && chown -R pptruser:pptruser ./package.json \
  && chown -R pptruser:pptruser ./package-lock.json \
  && chown -R pptruser:pptruser ./build \
  && mkdir -p /files \
  && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /files

RUN touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
RUN chmod 777 /etc/authbind/byport/80


RUN echo $(ls -la)

EXPOSE 80

USER pptruser

ENTRYPOINT [ "authbind", "--deep","node", "./build/main.js"]
```

```
Error Stack Trace - 
Error: Navigating frame was detached

at #removeFramesRecursively (/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/FrameManager.js:454:15)

at #onClientDisconnect (/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/FrameManager.js:102:42)

at Array.map (<anonymous>)

at #onFrameDetached (/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/cdp/LifecycleWatcher.js:109:47)

at Object.emit (/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/mitt/mitt.js:1:716)

at /node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/mitt/mitt.js:1:732

at CdpFrame.emit (/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:91:23)

Error: Navigating frame was detached
```

I am trying to navigate to a page using puppeteer. I am running puppeteer on a Docker Node 16 image. This used to work but now I am getting this Navigating frame was detached error on page.goto. I have tried using Node 18 and Node 21 on Docker as well as Puppeteer version 19 as well as the latest version 21.5.2 and I still have this error.

Note that I am skipping the default Chromium download that comes with Puppeteer and instead I set the executablePath argument to the latest Google Chrome Stable version downloaded in my Docker image. I have tried this same code with puppeteer-core as well instead of puppeteer in the import statement but I still have the same error.

Comment: Which URL? The code looks OK so a [mcve] seems to be necessary to help. Stating what you're trying to achieve is also useful.

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:docker].  If it's Docker-related (does the setup work with plain Node?) then it'd also be essential to include details on how you're building an image and running a container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I included my Dockerfile. I edited my original post to make it a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @ggorlen I updated my original post to make it a minimal reproducible example. Like I said in my original post, this code was working as expected but now it doesn't seem to work. If I use an older build that runs Node 16 on Docker and puppeteer:19.11.1, the same code with the same Dockerfile settings works for navigating to the same URLs on page.goto(). So I dont know what changed that is making my code to not work.